# CSS: How to affect :after Pseudo Element if Last-Child <li> gets hovered?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, pseudo-element

**Challenge:**

- A pseudo element called `li:last-child:after` should get affected when hovering `<li>` elements of a list
- The pseudo element should get affected depending on which `<li>` is getting `:hovered`

Example:

- Hovering `li:nth-child(1)` should move the pseudo element `100px` to the right,
- Hovering `li:nth-child(2)` should move the pseudo element `200 px` to the right, etc.

**Coding:**

For `<li>` items from 1 to 3 I got this work successfully, but unfortunately not for the last child. Where is my issue?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100px; height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}

/*Creating the pseudo element */
li:last-child:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;  left: 100px;
  width: 50px;  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

/*Creating the desired action for li childs 1 to 3*/
li:nth-child(1):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(100px);}
li:nth-child(2):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(200px);}
li:nth-child(3):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(300px);}

/*Failed experiments about creating the desired action for li last child*/
li:nth-child(4):hover + li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(400px);}
li:nth-child(4):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(400px);}
li:nth-child(4):hover > li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(400px);}
li:nth-child(4):hover li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(400px);}
```

```html
<div>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Because the 4th element IS the last child

Comment: Is there any reason you can’t create an empty `<li>` as your last child and use that as your red block? Get rid of the after pseudo and just target the empty li as last-child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li:nth-child(4):hover` is already saying

> li, which is the 4th element, which is being hovered

so `li:nth-child(4):hover + li:last-child:after` is looking for a 5th `li` sibling that immediately follows the 4th element and is also the last child.

`li:nth-child(4):hover ~ li:last-child:after` is looking for a 5th `li` sibling that is somewhere after the 4th element and is also the last child.

`li:nth-child(4):hover > li:last-child:after` is looking for an `li` that is a child of the 4th `li` and is also a last child.

and `li:nth-child(4):hover li:last-child:after` is looking for an `li` that is a descendant of the 4th `li` and is also a last child.

depending on what you're looking for you can either use:

`li:nth-child(4):hover:after { transform: translatex(400px);}`

`li:last-child:hover:after { transform: translatex(400px);}`

or `li:nth-child(4):hover:last-child:after { transform: translatex(400px);}` if you want to be consistent with the other ones.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100px; height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}

/*Creating the pseudo element */
li:last-child:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;  left: 100px;
  width: 50px;  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

/*Creating the desired action for li childs 1 to 3*/
li:nth-child(1):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(100px);}
li:nth-child(2):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(200px);}
li:nth-child(3):hover ~ li:last-child:after { transform: translatex(300px);}


li:nth-child(4):hover:last-child:after { transform: translatex(400px);}
```

```html
<div>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that hovering over the red square will now trigger that 4th `li`'s hover. You can fix this using `li:last-child:after { pointer-events: none; }`

Answer (score 1):

**For the last child, a different approach was necessary:**

```
li:last-child:hover:after { transform: translatex(400px);}
```